# IBM Watson Personality insight Demo Edit Issue

Tags: ibm-watson, personality-insights

I recently download IBM Watson personality insight demo (nodejs). when i am running that demo and trying to analyze any person that is already in list than it throws a error.
Here is the UI of that demo

[image]
 I don't know why is it coming. please guide me accordingly.
Here is an error 
[image]

Comment: Please include errors as text rather than a screenshot wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you are not authorised. You need to create a personality insights service, and set the credentials.

You can't use the default settings.

Comment: i added the credentials to manifest.yml file. i addes username and password of service.

Comment: service details don't go into the manifest.yml file. They go into the .env file. You should read the installation instructions:  https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-nodejs

Comment: ohh sorry. i addes the credentials in .env file. wait let me show u

Comment: Do not post your username/password publically.

Comment: so how can i solve it? i added the credentials in .env file but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: i figured out my mistake. thanks for help :) i was mistaking in syntax in writing credentials in .env file

Comment: great! don't forget to mark your question answered. :)

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty care to take a look at my problem?I would be very thankful If you could help me `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50006469/iterationg-through-gson-object`

Answer (score 0):

Double check your .env file.

> IBM Cloud is migrating to token-based Identity and Access Management (IAM) authentication.
>
> - With some service instances, you authenticate to the API by using IAM. You can pass either a bearer token in an Authorization header or an API key. Tokens support authenticated requests without embedding service credentials in every call. API keys use basic authentication. Learn more about IAM.
> - If you pass in an API key, use apikey for the username and the value of the API key as the password.
> - In other instances, you authenticate by providing the username and password for the service instance. For more information, see Service credentials for Watson services.
>
> To find out which authentication to use, view the service credentials by clicking the service instance on the Dashboard.

Source : [apidocs/personality-insights](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/personality-insights)

So in your `.env`file the service credentials could either be

```
# service credentials 
PERSONALITY_INSIGHTS_USERNAME= <YOUR USERNAME>
PERSONALITY_INSIGHTS_PASSWORD= <YOUR PASSWORD>
PERSONALITY_INSIGHTS_URL=<SERVICE URL>
```

Or

```
# service credentials 
PERSONALITY_INSIGHTS_IAM_APIKEY= <YOUR API KEY> 
PERSONALITY_INSIGHTS_URL= <SERVICE URL>
```